# How to fit text in trapezium?

Tags: tikz-styles

How can I arrange the text inside a trapezium to be completely fitted inside of it?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes, positioning}

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
                           minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
                           text centered, font=\sffamily},
           data/.style = {base, trapezium,
                          trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70, inner xsep=-7pt, font=\sffamily, fill=YellowGreen},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center]
    \node (RS) [data, align=center] {Reconfiguration\\ Plan};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is caused by the `inner xsep=-7pt`. Increasing that to say `0pt` works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.